# Simple XSLT Text Replacement

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm looking for a simpler, more elegant way to replace text in XML.  For a source XML like:

```
<A>
 <B>
  <Name>ThisOne</Name>
  <Target>abc</Target>
 </B>
 <B>
  <Name>NotThisOne</Name>
  <Target>abc</Target>
 </B>
 <B>
  <Name>ThisOne</Name>
  <Target>def</Target>
 </B>
</A>
```

I want to change the text of all Target elements that have the Name of "ThisOne" to "xyz".

The result would be:

```
<A>
 <B>
  <Name>ThisOne</Name>
  <Target>xyz</Target>     <--   Changed.
 </B>
 <B>
  <Name>NotThisOne</Name>
  <Target>abc</Target>
 </B>
 <B>
  <Name>ThisOne</Name>
  <Target>xyz</Target>     <--   Changed.
 </B>
</A>
```

I accomplished this with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="B/Target">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="../Name/text()='ThisOne'"><Target>xyz</Target></xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise><Target><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></Target></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I was thinking this could be done with <xsl:template match="B/Target/text()">, so I could just replace the text and not the whole element, but I couldn't figure out the rest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting  - 3 very similar answers within a few minutes - I would really welcome a stylistic compare and contrast from one of the real experts here. *Especially* if it pointed out improvements to my solution

Comment: @Kevan - The only issue with your answer is that if the `<Target>` element contained any attributes, they would be stripped.

Comment: @DevNull - Good point - your /text() <xsl:text> style is less likely to behave unexpectedly were the input document to change and start having attributes on the Target element - I'm glad I asked :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="B[Name='ThisOne']/Target/text()">
    <xsl:text>xyz</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

using your XML input produces:

```
<A>
  <B>
    <Name>ThisOne</Name>
    <Target>xyz</Target>
  </B>
  <B>
    <Name>NotThisOne</Name>
    <Target>abc</Target>
  </B>
  <B>
    <Name>ThisOne</Name>
    <Target>xyz</Target>
  </B>
</A>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is all you have to do:

```
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="B/Target[../Name='ThisOne']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:text>xyz</xsl:text>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

The first template is the "identity transform" and copies input to output unchanged. The second matches the specific targets you want to change, copies the tag and attributes, and substitutes the desired text.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cds="cds_dt" exclude-result-prefixes="cds">
    <!-- Identity transfrom - just copy what doesn't need changing -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- a rule for what does need changing -->
    <!-- Change all Target nodes whose parent has a child of Name equal to ThisOne -->
    <xsl:template match="/A/B[Name='ThisOne']/Target">
        <Target>xyz</Target>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is certainly cleaner, but doesn't eliminate having to replace the whole element, instead of just the text.